# rails 4 eager loading - order nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have 4 models

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :Bs
end 

class B < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :A
  has_many :Cs
  has_many :Ds
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :B
end

class D < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :B
end
```

I need to eager load A, and get all nested associations. So from A:

```
eager_load(Bs: [:Cs, :Ds]).where('id=?',id).to_a
```

Now I want to order B records through the eager loading. I tried to add the order through the association like this:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :Bs, -> { order("id desc") }
end
```

But it doesn't work. When I do something like

```
A.first.bs
```

B records are not ordered by id desc.

Could you please advice on this one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but you could do this to order the `Bs` by id or any other field you like:

`eager_load(Bs: [:Cs, :Ds]).where('id=?',id).order('Bs.id DESC')`

The other option would be to setup a default scope on the model, like so:

```
def self.default_scope
  order(id: :desc)
end
```